# get percentage along with group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, percentage

I am using a join query to get data grouped by titles where titles are stored in another table with user id

so the query is like following

```
SELECT title, COUNT(title) as cnt FROM users_titles
JOIN users
ON users_titles.uid = users.uid
WHERE users.useractivated = 1
GROUP BY title
```

Now I wan to add an extra column which will show the percentage of each type like following:

```
----------------------------------
| title   |   cnt   | percentage |
----------------------------------
| 0       | 23658   | 23.67%     |
----------------------------------
| 1       | 53658   | 43.67%     |
----------------------------------
```

some thing like this. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cross join this query with a query counting the total number of users, and divide the two counts to get a percentage:

```
SELECT     title, COUNT(title) AS cnt, COUNT(title) / total_count AS percentage
FROM       users_titles
JOIN       users ON users_titles.uid = users.uid
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count 
            FROM   users) t 
WHERE      users.useractivated = 1
GROUP BY   title
```

Note: If you want to represent the number as a percentage from the active users, you'd need to add a `WHERE users.useractivated = 1` clause to the inner query too.